# Typescript type for an array that can contain only elements from a specific list

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, enums, typescript-typings

I want to declare a type for an array that can contain maximum one of the following strings: `'first'`, `'second'`, `'third'`.

Some valid examples of how that array could be:

- `[]`
- `[ 'first' ]`
- `[ 'first', 'second' ]`
- `[ 'first', 'second', 'third' ]`
- `[ 'first', 'third' ]`
- `[ 'second', 'third' ]`

Some invalid arrays:

- `[ 'other-value' ]` // no other values should be accepted
- `[ 'first', 'first' ]` // no duplicates accepted

The types I've wrote:

```
export enum MyOptions {
  first = 'first',
  second = 'second',
  third = 'third'
}

export type MyType = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  listings: {
   MyOptions;
  }[];
};
```

It has a warning saying *Member 'MyOptions' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage*.

So if it is changed to:

```
export type MyType = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  listings: {
   options: MyOptions;
  }[];
};
```

Now, there is no warning but it has that extra `options` value that I don't think it must be added.

Any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Set` data structure.

```js
export type Options = 'first' | 'second' | 'third'
export type Listing = Set<Options>

export type MyType = {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    listings: Listing;
};

const myType = {
  name: 'name',
  email: 'email',
  listing: new Set(['first', 'second'])
}
```

Then you will be sure that there are no repeated options in your listing.
Note: actually you can pass repeated options but `Set` will ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an extra set of braces that you don't need.

```js
export type MyType = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  listings: {
   MyOptions;
  }[];
};
```

should be changed to

```js
export type MyType = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  listings: MyOptions[];
};
```

You also have a more concise option: use string literal types:

```js
export type MyType = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  listings: ('first' | 'second' | 'third')[];
};
```

Comment: it seems that your answer accepts duplicates (`[ 'first', 'first' ]`) too which should not, I added it as invalid arrays in the question's body, maybe it wasn't clear before

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
export type MyType = {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    listings: MyOptions[];
};
```

Let's assume you have variable named `x` of `MyType`, then to push new value to `listings` member you can do `x.listings.push(MyOptions.first)`

Answer (score 0):

The second solution just means that you now have an object that could look like:

```
const exampleObject = {
  name: 'Ralf';
  email: 'XXX@XX.xx';
  listings: {
   options: 'first';
  }[];
};
```

Which is not what you intend, because you can´t have a ['first', 'second'] there, but only ONE value.

If you use the style

```
listings: MyOptions[];
```

Then it allows also the content `['first', 'first']`.

As far as i know, there is no way to limit the possible values not only by its content, but also by its amount (having at maximum one of each values) via typescript types.

So you would have to create your own logic.

For example having a small business object

```
class Options {
  private _values: MyOptions[] = [];

  addOption(option:MyOption){
    if(this._values.some(option)){
      return; // or throw an error, depends on your usecase
    }
    this.values.concat(option);
  }

  get options():MyOptions{
    return this._values;
  }
}
```

Now you can have your wrapper type:

```
export type MyType = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  listings: Options
};
```